# Нет текстуры на префабе/ префаб полностью прозрачен. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Сделал Image объект, накинул на него скрипт, текстуру, цвет. Сам объект такой, какой я хочу. При клонировании через Ctrl+c/V всё тоже нормально, свойства сохраняются. Когда я кидаю его в папку с префабами, создаётся префаб(как ни странно). Когда другой скрипт размещает префабы или даже когда я перетаскиваю префаб на сцену, то он полностью прозрачный. В инспекторе есть все свойства от созданного мною геймобжекта, в т.ч текстура, скрипт, цвет. Пересоздавал объект и после префаб кучу раз, ничего не помогло. Может кто-то ещё с этим сталкивался?

UPD: Префаб у меня отдельно от Canvas спавнится, отдельно от Canvasa походу Image не отображается